# CR-10S Pro direct drive upgrade

Tags: creality-cr-10, direct-drive, automatic-bed-leveling

I am looking at getting a direct drive upgrade kit for my Creality CR-10s Pro printer  (e.g. on Amazon there is one with brand name Yeebyee). My question is about whether these kits support the autolevel sensor on my printer.  The pictures of the kit installed don't show the sensor. Is it possible to install the sensor with one of these kits?

Comment: The direct drive has nothing to do with the auto-level sensor. Once the sensor determines the mesh for the bed, the print starts and it doesn't get used again until the next print while the direct drive is in use during the print itself.

Comment: But on the OEM configuration, the auto-level sensor is mounted right next to the hotend. The direct drive upgrade replaces the bracket that holds the hotend. Can I mount the sensor right next to the hotend on the new bracket?